# Communicating between Node.Js and ASP.NET MVC Application

Tags: asp.net-mvc, node.js, socket.io

I have an existing complex website built using ASP.NET MVC, including a database backend, data layer, as well as the Web UI layer. Rebuilding this website in another language is not a feasible option.

There are some UI elements on some views (client side) which would benefit from live interactivity, involving both push and pull, so rather than implement some kind of custom long polling or websocket server in asp.net, I am looking to leverage node.js for Windows, and Socket.io.

My problem is that I need two way communication between both applications. Each user should only be able to receive data once they are authorised on the ASP.NET website, so I first need communication for this. Secondly, once certain events occur on the ASP.NET website I want to immediately push this data to the Node server, to be broadcast to specific users or groups of users. Thirdly, I would like any data sent to the node.js server to be pushed to the ASP.NET website for processing, as this is where all our business logic lies. The sole reason for adding Node.js is to have the possibility to push data directly to the client, I do not want to build any business logic into it (or as little as possible).

I would like to know what the fastest method of two-way push communication is between Node.Js and ASP.NET. The only good option I'm aware of so far is to create a special listener on a specific port on the node.js server and connect to that, but I was wondering if there's a more elegant or more efficient method? I also know that you could use a database inbetween but surely this would need to be polled and would be less efficient? Both servers will be running on the same server under a Visual Studio project.

Many thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: For newcomers to this question, there's a library called [EdgeJS](http://tjanczuk.github.io/edge/#/) that is an alternative to the proposed solutions. Best thing is that it goes both ways - you can have .NET or Node as the controlling process.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not an ASP.NET expert, but I *think* there are multiple ways you can achieve this:

1) As you said, you could make Node listen on a specific port for data and then react based on the data received (TCP)
2) You can make POST requests to Node.js (HTTP) and also send an auth-key in the process to be extra-secure. Like on 1) Node would react to the data you send.
3) Use something like [Redis](http://redis.io) for pub-sub, send messages from ASP.NET (pub) and get them on the Node.js part (sub). This is even better if you want to scale your app across multiple machines etc.

Answer (score 2):

> The only good option I'm aware of so far is to create a special
>   listener on a specific port on the node.js server and connect to that,
>   but I was wondering if there's a more elegant or more efficient
>   method?

You can try to look at [redis pub/sub](http://redis.io/topics/pubsub) model where ASP.NET MVC application and node.js would communicate through separate channels in order to achieve full-duplex communication. Or you can also try to use [CouchDB change nofitications](http://guide.couchdb.org/draft/notifications.html).

> I also know that you could use a database inbetween but surely this
>   would need to be polled and would be less efficient?

Former techniques do not require you to poll for changes, but instead they will notify you when the changes happens or channel message arrives.