# Subscribing to ServiceBus for Notifications

Tags: asp.net-mvc, node.js, redis, masstransit

I've been doing some reading up this morning on developing client notification systems, and nodeJS seems to be part of my solution.

This question gave me some ideas, but I think what I want is a little more. And, it left me (after some research) with questions as to using Redis on a Windows server.

[Communicating between Node.Js and ASP.NET MVC Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091031/communicating-between-node-js-and-asp-net-mvc-application)

So, to my question.  I'm currently using MassTransit, and I'm happy with pub/sub in there, but how do I notify my clients? If I use nodejs to allow something like socketio to create connections with, I'm not seeing how I link node to my mvc layer.

I'm going to release this into a production Windows environment, so I can't use redis if it's not stable on Windows. It sounded like that would have been my missing link.

edit: I did intend to ask if couchdb is an option, and is it stable on windows as an alternative to redid?

Comment: I have removed your couchdb tag as I don't see any relation to couchdb. Please clarify if I am wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [ZeroMQ](http://www.zeromq.org/intro:get-the-software), it can manage your pub-sub if you don't want to rely on Redis or you can just use MassTransit with the Node.js library from here: https://github.com/enix/MassTransit-JS

You really don't have to link your MVC app with your Socket.IO code, what you should do is keep them de-coupled and communicating through pub-sub. So each time you want to send a message to notify the users, you publish a message and the SocketIO logic gets it (being subscribed to a specific pubsub channel).

Another useful resource: [Communicating between Node.Js and ASP.NET MVC Application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8091031/communicating-between-node-js-and-asp-net-mvc-application)